# Hi guys am getting a php fatal error while running my Laravel Project in Composer, I cannot run any php artisan commands without getting errors

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Am getting a php fatal error while running my Laravel Project in Composer, I cannot run any php artisan commands without getting errors.
This is the error am getting.

```html
$ php artisan
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::of
fsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework
\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1277
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444): include('...')
#2 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#3 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(109): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): collect()
#5 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
#6 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#7 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(219): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#8 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
#9 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#10 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#11 {main} in C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php on line 11

In Collection.php line 11:

  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mi
  xed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill
  uminate\Support\Collection.php:1277
  Stack trace:
  #0 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
  #1 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444): include('...')
  #2 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
  #3 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(109): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
  #4 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): collect()
  #5 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
  #6 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
  #7 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(219): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
  #8 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
  #9 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
  #10 C:\Projects\Duffengi\duffengi\duffengi\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
  #11 {main}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like maybe a php version or composer version issue, not sure if you saw this link. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-fatal-error-during-inheritance-of-arrayaccess-uncaught-errorexception-return-type-of-illuminatesupportcollectionoffsetexistskey

Comment: Let me take a look. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this even related to Composer itself?

Comment: I have tried to update the composer and also to change the php versions but that hasn't worked

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. There's no need to randomly change anything. Just restore the last working state of your application, and tell us what you've changed from that state to the current one